# Why is there no signature separator “--” when responding, but it appears in a new message?

Tags: thunderbird, email-signature

I'm using Thunderbird 10.0.2 on Mac and have a simple text signature.

When I write new message, Thunderbird automatically adds `--` before the signature, but when I click on reply to a message, it doesn’t.

How can I get it to always add the `--` before my signature?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Setting it up for appending after quote of original message appears to retain the `'-- '` separator. You can configure it in:

**Account-Settings** -> Your Account -> **Composition and Addressing** -> **and place my signature** set to **below the quote**.

This setting is appropriate for [bottom posting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_post#Bottom-posting).

Comment: Yes, there has to be a space after the -- for it to work.  Most Usenet clients acknowledge it as well, and so strip out the signature on replies.